# memory error for PCA in python

Tags: python, pca

I am implementing a PCA algorithm in python with the standard svd function, i.e.,

```
u, s, v = svd(sigma)
```

The original space has 4800 dimensions, i.e., sigma is a 4800*4800 matrix.

The dimension seems not too large, but I always come across ``Memory Error'' in svd function. My computer is 32-bit windows 7.

So what is the problem? And what is the typical feature dimensions that the svd algorithm can solve?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out `numpy` and `numpy.array`. They consume a lot less memory than Python lists.

Answer (score 2):

You state standard svd function - but from where there is not one by standard in python you could be using one from numpy, scipy or several other places, (this is why *"namespaces are a honking good idea"*).

From basic principles 4800*4800=23,040,000 i.e. 23 million entries, if each of those entries is a single byte, (which I doubt), then you will be using 23MB for each matrix and it looks like you are getting back 3 results so with the original that is 23*4 = 92MB but you are almost certain to be using float or double which will multiply that by 4 or 8 to give up to 1GB ***without any intermediate results***... Win7/32 has a max memory map of just under 3 GB, (if you have that much or more fitted), to fit OS, Drivers, Graphics, etc.  You will find that some implementations are more efficient than others and more tolerant of needing to use virtual memory.

As python can be run on a lot of platforms from tiny, e.g. RaspberryPi or embedded solution through various PC configurations, e.g. 512 MB DOS machine or Linux 64 bit with 32 GB of ram  to a single supercomputer or a cluster of machines working as a supercomputing cluster so you are unlikely to find a simple "this works for matrices up to NxM" figure.

Comment: Thanks. But I was told that PCA works well within thousands of features. When I called the svd function, which is probably standard for implementing PCA (since it is more numerically stable than the eig function), the python just ran out of memory on a modern PC.